# How can I prevent changing of networks?

Tags: security, user-account, accessibility

Is there a ways to prevent people from changing wireless networks and other networks?

Does Apple have any kind of ACLs or something like Windows where you can control what the users can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Require Administrator for AirPort

You can set up your computer to require an administrator password to change AirPort settings, including changing networks.

1. Open **System Preferences** → **Network**.

   [image]
2. Select your **WiFi** service in the services list.

   [image]
3. Click **Advanced…** in the bottom-right corner.

   [image]
4. Select the options that you would like to require administrator authorization for.

   [image]
5. Click **OK**, then **Apply**.

Comment: Nicely done, you just added screenshots to yours but basically copied what I said. Normally one would just modify, enhance the existing answer.

Comment: @Buscar웃 You [just edited](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/102362/revisions) your answer to match what I said. You were talking about locking the System Preference *pane* originally…